# MongoDB $geoIntersects cannot find Polygons that contain a given Point

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I have a document in the database that contains a "polygon" property that, as far as I can tell, is a valid GeoJSON object. I want to search the database using a GeoJSON Point object to find documents where the polygon in the polygon property contains the Point. To do so, I am using the $geoIntersects operator, however, whenever I preform the find, MongoDB returns the error: [Error: Can't use $geoIntersects].

The only object in the database:

```
{  
    "_id": ObjectId("581540795fd2da1b188eb09c"),
    "name":"String",
    "polygon":{  
        "coordinates":[  
            [ -90, -180 ],
            [ 90, -180 ],
            [ 90, 180 ],
            [ -90, 180 ],
            [ -90, -180 ]
        ],
        "_id": ObjectId("581540795fd2da1b188eb09d"),
        "name": "String",
        "type": "Polygon"
    },
    "__v":0
}
```

I am using mongoose to search the database. The query that is used to preform the search:

```
{
    polygon: {
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [<long>, <lat>]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I set the latitude and longitude to something simple, say (0, 0) or (1, 1). It returns the error. According to what I read elsewhere, the only reason this error should be returned is because the documents in the database are not valid GeoJSON objects, but I cannot see anything wrong with the only object in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the outer array on your coordinates for a geoJSON polygon.  Your document should look like this:

```
{  
    "_id": ObjectId("581540795fd2da1b188eb09c"),
    "name":"String",
    "polygon":{  
        "coordinates":[[  
            [ -90, -180 ],
            [ 90, -180 ],
            [ 90, 180 ],
            [ -90, 180 ],
            [ -90, -180 ]
        ]],
        "_id": ObjectId("581540795fd2da1b188eb09d"),
        "name": "String",
        "type": "Polygon"
    },
    "__v":0
}
```

From the geoJSON spec, http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#id4

> Coordinates of a Polygon are an array of LinearRing coordinate arrays. The first element in the array represents the exterior ring. Any subsequent elements represent interior rings (or holes).